# How to raise an error in Ruby on Rails if a function is not called in after_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Lets say I have a method in my model

```
class Mod < ...
   after_create :update_some_stuff

   private

   def update_some_stuff
       ....
   end
end
```

And I want to ensure that "update some stuff" is only called by after create, and to raise an error if it is called in any other context. Is there a way to do this in Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use a block and avoid doing weird tricks to prevent the method getting called outside the context you want:

```
after_create do
   ....
end
```

Comment: I'm using a system with subclassing so this won't work. The method in question is overridden by the subclass.

Answer (score 1):

It's hacky, and you probably don't need to be testing this because Rails tests this for you, but this should work:

```
class Mod < ...
   after_create :update_some_stuff

   private

   def update_some_stuff
     return unless id_previously_changed?
     # do something
   end
end
```

This hooks into `previous_changes` which is implemented by [`ActiveModel::Dirty`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html).